# Performance of OR vs UNION in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out the `Spark-Sql` query performance with `OR` vs `IN` vs `UNION ALL`.

Option-1:

```
select cust_id, prod_id, prod_typ
from cust_prod
where prod_typ = '0102' OR prod_typ = '0265';
```

Option-2:

```
select cust_id, prod_id, prod_typ
from cust_prod
where prod_typ IN ('0102, '0265');
```

Option-3:

```
select cust_id, prod_id, prod_type
from cust_prod
where prod_typ = '0102'
union all
select cust_id, prod_id, prod_type
from cust_prod
where prod_typ = '0265';
```

I have checked the query plans for all of the above options and have found that with `OR`, the source table is scanned only **ONCE**. However, with `UNION ALL` I found that the source table is being scanned twice. Hence, logically speaking, the query using `OR` and `IN` would be more efficient than the one with `UNION ALL`.

But I read somewhere that the `UNION ALL` is preferred (over `OR`) in such scenarios. Hence, I am bit confused as to which one to follow - `OR` vs `IN` vs `UNION ALL`.

Can anyone please help me understand which is the right approach. Any help is highly appreciated.

Note: We use SparkSQL version `2.4.0`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Union All` can also be made to reuse `exchanges` in specific situations by excluding `optimizer`'s rule `PushDownPredicate` in some instances.